# Best practice for dealing with lost packages during shipping

Tags: magento2, extensions, shipping, stock

**Using:**
Magento 2.4.6
Hyva magento2 default theme: 1.2.3

**Subject:**
What is a good way to handle lost packages during shipping?

**Situation is as follows:**
Product gets paid.
Product is shipped to customer via mailbox mail.
There is no track and trace.
Customer sends a message that he/she didn't receive the product.

**Conclusion:** product is lost during shipment and customer needs a new shipment to replace the lost product.

**Issue:**
Now the shop owner needs to,
resend the same product for the already paid order,
update the stock status while having multi source inventories,
be able to get data for getting insight in how many times this happens,
what the total costs are for shipping costs and product costs, not only for this product but for all products that are lost during shipment.

**Requirements would be:**
To be able to keep track of incoming customer requests for new shipments.
Get insight in costs and frequency during a time period, of lost packages.
Correctly update stock status for multiply inventories.

**Questions:**
Are there any extensions that can give insight in this data and be able to handle the request or what would be a good way to approach this situation?